# Error while connecting to SQL Server from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

This error occurs when I was trying to connect to SQL Server 2005 which is there with VS 2008.

> AN ERROR HAS OCCURRED WHILE ESTABLISHING CONNECTION TO THE SQL SERVER
>   2005. THIS FAILURE MAY BE CAUSED BY THE FACT THAT UNDER THE DEFAULT SETTINGS SQL SERVER DOES NOT ALLOW REMOTE CONNECTIONS.(PROVIDER:SQL
>   NETWORK INTERFACE, ERROR:26. ERROR LOCATING SERVER/INSTANCE
>   SPECIFIED.)

I am doing everything on local machine still it shows error for network. I tried to enable SQL Server browser but its not starting anyway.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Is your connection string correct?

Comment: Check that MSSQL server is running: run *services.msc* and find the *SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)* service, make sure it is running.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Exception---error-26---Error-Locating-Server-Instance-Specified.aspx

Comment: @ oleksii: I checked the service is running and active....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the rights of the folder in which your .net and inbuilt sql server is reside.
You have to full rights of that folder.

Comment: :Thanks Vishal, Will u plse let me know how to give full rights to the folder?

Comment: Select the folder in which your application reside and right click on that folder. Then go to the security tab and then give full rights to user from which you are logged in.